# Multi-tenant socks

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

So I have a this awesome multi-tenant project I made with Django. I have it deployed on heroku and everything is good to go. BUT its multi-tenant so I need things like customer1.site.com and customer2.site.com

I got this working on my side because my computer has a static IP address so I can just route *.site.com to my IP address and then everything works.

Heroku doesn't have this ability of static ip addresses. So how can I get past this? I need a cost effective way to solve this. The solutions I see are mainly addons for outbound traffic only. I simply need to route all traffic to *.site.com to an ip address that will show my application on heroku.

I in theory can do something like *.app.site.com and route all that traffic to app.herokuapp.com but customer.app.site.com seems way to much honestly. Plus it looks tacky. Has anyone does anything to figure this out?strong text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can route wildcard domain to Heroku as shown in its [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain)

> `heroku domains:add *.example.com`

---

> Use the * wildcard subdomain notation to add a CNAME record to
>   encircled-magnolia-9265.herokudns.com. with your DNS provider.